# Images are not displaying in carousel

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have a image carousel that is not displaying images at:
[carousel - images not displaying](http://patskailua.com/navbar-fadev4.html)

I compared it to a working carousel and the code is almost identical at:
[carousel - images are displaying](http://tahoe-luxury-properties.com/navbar-fadev3.html)

I tested the images from the non working carousel in the working carousel and they show up, so it is not the images.

I am really not sure why the images are not displaying. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks so much.

Comment: Please post the code you used for the carousel.

Comment: There is nothing in your slides. Try with some images... For fun, add this in the `$(document).ready()` : `$(".carousel-inner .item").css({"background-color":"blue","border":"4px solid red","height":"400px"});`. You will see that the carousel is working fine.

Comment: Here is a fiddle with the code: https://jsfiddle.net/bgnj9chm/

Comment: The images are located in the css and referenced to in the html to call them up. It is working fine in the carousel at: http://tahoe-luxury-properties.com/navbar-fadev3.html

Comment: are you looking for carousel slider in background?

Comment: The slides are set as background images in css: .slide1 {
 background-image: url(http://tahoe-luxury-properties.com/images/325-squaw-valley-road-squaw-valley-olympic-valley-ca-96146.jpg);
}
.slide2 {
 background-image: url(http://tahoe-luxury-properties.com/images/summit-place-view.jpg);
}
.slide3 {
 background-image: url(http://tahoe-luxury-properties.com/images/gonowabi-living-area2.png);
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Forgot Closing brace for this Class `.navbar-default.transparent` 
CSS

```
.navbar-default.transparent {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    height: 100px;
    /* height: 100px;*/
    }
```

Hope this Helps..

Comment: but when i inspect the site, it is not showing up. Why??

Comment: The code is on lines 40-43 on the document: http://patskailua.com/navbar-fadev4.html

Comment: @BethAbernathy, Check the code I have updated, that was a syntax issue.

Answer (score 0):

Always use [Nu Html Checker](https://validator.w3.org/)

Thanks to all.